# Partial integration involving CDF

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, integral

I am reading a textbook which claims that we can obtain by partial integration, for CDF $F(x)$:$$\int_{t}^{\infty} (1-F(x))  \frac{dx}{x}=\int_{t}^{\infty} (\log u -\log t) dF(u) $$

I am aware that the latter integral is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, but I am not sure how to go from the first to the latter via the partial integration formula I am familiar with, I obtain:

$$\int_{t}^{\infty} (1-F(x))\frac{dx}{x}=\log(x)(1-F(x)|_{t}^{\infty}) -\int_{t}^{\infty}\log(x)(1-F(x)) dx.$$

Comment: If anyone's still interested in this question, it has been answered [on the Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2956305/partial-integration-cdf).

Comment: Because it's answered there, it would accomplish nothing to migrate this question to the Math site.